# Pyzo will not start after fontcolor change

Tags: installation, themes, pyzo

I am currently using Pyzo and changed its font and background color according to the instructions on their website (http://www.pyzo.org/pyzo_themes.html) by changing the **init**() in the base.py file. Everything was fine until I wanted to change the settings back to normal. When I try to open any .py file Pyzo gives me the error

"Error loading file: local variable fore1 referenced before assignment".

On closing the error message, the Shell just keeps warming up and nothing happens. On the left side where the editor would have been, there is a small white box with a smaller yellow one inside.

Opening up Pyzo on its own does not give the error, but the same problem with the Shell and editor.

I tried:

- changing the settings in base.py manually to their default value
- copying the backup file I made before the changes back into the directory
- uninstalling Pyzo with IOBit Uninstaller to catch all hidden files and  reinstall it (about 10 times already)

I thought reinstalling it would resolve the matter but obviously there must be a different issue here. I really hope someone had the same problem, thanks in advance for any help!